# SilverStripe and Display Logic fails with certain field types

Tags: silverstripe

I'm working on a SilverStripe 3.1.8 site. I have a DataExtension that defines some fields, and I'm trying to use Display Logic to modify the behavior of the CMS:

```
private static $db = array(
    'Enabled' => 'Boolean',
    'Title' => 'Text'
);
private static $has_one = array(
    'Link' => 'SiteTree',
    'Image' => 'Image'
);

/* this is a DataExtension */
public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Other', array(
        CheckboxField::create('Enabled'),
        TextField::create('Title', "Title")->displayIf('Enabled')->isChecked()->end(),
        TreeDropdownField::create("LinkID", "Linked page", 'SiteTree')->displayIf('Enabled')->isChecked()->end(),
        UploadField::create('Image', "Image")->displayIf('Enabled')->isChecked()->end()
    ));

}
```

When I check or uncheck the "Enabled" checkbox, the other three fields should appear or disappear correspondingly. Unfortunately, only the TextField does, the TreeDropdownField and UploadField are always shown.

Any ideas why Display Logic fails with these two field types, and how to solve it?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you know which version of display logic module you are using?

Comment: Hi Cam, I'm using the latest commit from the master branch at https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic. Also, the problem remains after upgrading to SilverStrip 3.1.9

Comment: Can you try using 1.0.8 of display logic https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic/releases/tag/1.0.8 see what happens there. Are you using composer to sort dependancies?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that **UploadField** and **DropdownField** fall under the category of [Dealing with non-standard forms](https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic#dealing-with-non-standard-form-fields) and you need to wrap them in a **DisplayLogicWrapper**.

See the last 2 lines of the *addFieldsToTab* input array.

```
private static $db = array(
    'Enabled' => 'Boolean',
    'Title' => 'Text'
);
private static $has_one = array(
    'Link' => 'SiteTree',
    'Image' => 'Image'
);

/* this is a DataExtension */
public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Other', array(
        CheckboxField::create('Enabled'),
        TextField::create('Title', "Title")->displayIf('Enabled')->isChecked()->end(),
        DisplayLogicWrapper::create(TreeDropdownField::create("LinkID", "Linked page", 'SiteTree'))->displayIf('Enabled')->isChecked()->end(),
        DisplayLogicWrapper::create(UploadField::create('Image', "Image"))->displayIf('Enabled')->isChecked()->end()
    ));

}
```

Comment: P.S. I also found I had to use the _master-dev_ version of the module. The _stable_ version does not work.

Comment: Hi Atari, I cannot check now, but I did try DisplayLogicWrapper. That didn't work, and the only difference was that DisplayLogicWrapper made the visual horizontal line that separates the fields in the form disappear. 

I'll test with master-dev and version 1.0.8 (suggested by Cam above) as soon as I can.

Comment: Yeah, It changes the CSS styling, but my present version using an UploadField works - hope it works for you - as I said, use the _master-dev_ version, not _stable_ - happy weekend! a.)